# Merging Dataframes with different column names with aggregated column values

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

Merging two dataframe : I have two dataframes that need merging on some criteria but i havent been able to figure out how to do this?

```
df1 : 

id            positive_action    date             volume  
id_1          user 1                  2016-12-12       19720.735
              user 2                  2016-12-12       14740.800

df2 :
id            negative_action        date             volume  
id_1          user 1                  2016-12-12       10.000
              user 3                  2016-12-12       10.000     

I want : 

id            action        date             volume  
id_1          user 1         2016-12-12       19730.735
              user 2         2016-12-12       14740.800   
              user 3         2016-12-12       10.000
```

Here

1. Volume is aggregated across both dataframes
2. merged on ID, Date and (positive action and negative action merged together)

How do i achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can also concatenate your DataFrames after renaming the positive_action and negative_action columns to just `action` and then perform a groupby.

```
df1.rename(columns={'positive_action':'action'}, inplace=True)
df2.rename(columns={'negative_action':'action'}, inplace=True)
pd.concat([df1, df2]).groupby(['id', 'action', 'date']).sum().reset_index()


     id  action        date     volume
0  id_1  user 1  2016-12-12  19730.735
1  id_1  user 2  2016-12-12  14740.800
2  id_1  user 3  2016-12-12     10.000
```

Answer (score 2):

This should work:

```
# not sure what indexing you are using so lets remove it
# to get on the same page, so to speak ;).
df1 = df1.reset_index()
df2 = df2.reset_index()

# do an outer merge to allow mismatches on the actions.
df = df1.merge(
    df2, left_on=['id', 'positive_action', 'date'],
    right_on=['id', 'negative_action', 'date'],
    how='outer',
)


# fill the missing actions from one with the other.
# (Will only happen when one is missing due to the way we merged.)
df['action'] = df['positive_action'].fillna(df['negative_action'])

# drop the old actions
df = df.drop('positive_action', 1)
df = df.drop('negative_action', 1)

# aggregate the volumes (I'm assuming you mean a simple sum)
df['volume'] = df['volume_x'].fillna(0) + df['volume_y'].fillna(0)

# drop the old volumes
df = df.drop('volume_x', 1)
df = df.drop('volume_y', 1)

print(df)
```

The output is:

```
     id        date     volume  action
0  id_1  2016-12-12  19730.735  user_1
1  id_1  2016-12-12  14740.800  user_2
2  id_1  2016-12-12     10.000  user_3
```

You can then restore the indexing I may have removed.

Answer (score 2):

- `set_index` on the columns you want to "merge" on
- `rename_axis` because when we `add` if we have inconsistently named index levels, it will make a panda cry.
- use `pd.Series.add` with parameter `fill_value=0`
- `rename_axis` again with the desired names
- `reset_index` and you're in business

---

```
v1 = df1.set_index(['positive_action', 'date']).volume.rename_axis([None, None])
v2 = df2.set_index(['negative_action', 'date']).volume.rename_axis([None, None])
v1.add(v2, fill_value=0).rename_axis(['action', 'date']).reset_index()

   action       date     volume
0  user 1 2016-12-12  19730.735
1  user 2 2016-12-12  14740.800
2  user 3 2016-12-12     10.000
```

---

***setup***

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame(dict(
        positive_action=['user 1', 'user 2'],
        date=pd.to_datetime(['2016-12-12', '2016-12-12']),
        volume=[19720.735, 14740.800]
    ))

df2 = pd.DataFrame(dict(
        negative_action=['user 1', 'user 3'],
        date=pd.to_datetime(['2016-12-12', '2016-12-12']),
        volume=[10, 10]
    ))
```